# how to merge classification models horizontally

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

I have many models already trained, which each answer a simple yes/no question. Pseudocode:

```
model_dog = keras.load('is_dog')
model_cat = keras.load('is_cat')
model_rat = keras.load('is_rat')

image = load_photo_as_numpy_array('photo.jpg')

multi_class = [ m.predict(image) for m in (model_dog,model_cat,model_rat) ]
```

This works fine, but it is a> slow because inference is done sequentially instead of in parallel (I have several hundred such models, not just 3), and b> is much more complex to use than if I had ONE model which does multi-classification.

What I want, is:

```
model = keras.concat_horizontal([ model_dog, model_cat, model_rat ])
model.save('combined_model')
```

Then whenever I want to use the combined model, it is as simple as:

```
model = keras.load('combined_model')
multi_class = m.predict(image)
```

This way, I can add a new classification to the combined model, by training one simple model, for example, that recognizes a fish.

Comment: I know there is a concat_horizontal for LAYERS, but not MODELS. Also, I looked at several similar questions on Stackoverflow before posting this -- not satisfied by any of their answers.

Comment: I realize this might be called an 'ensemble', but I think ensembles are about voting and merging votes into one final answer. I'm talking here about a different kind of ensemble. Each model is an expert in answering its own Y/N question; I want to run these models as if they were one model, and end up with a concatenation of the Y/N answers.

Comment: Can you link to documentation about this concat_horizontal function in Keras?

Comment: @freeideas There is no such a library. You should define a new input layer. Then link it to all your models. and gather the output layer of all models. Then define a new model with these input and outputs. Then you can save and load it.

Comment: @Kaveh: That sounds like exactly what I am trying to do. That might get me most or all the benefit I am looking for :)

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy: https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/concatenate/ ok maybe it isn't exactly what I described, but close.

Comment: Hmm. I might be able to take Kaveh's suggestion to define a single input layer that feeds the models, then use the layer concatenate that Dr.Snoopy asked about, to merge the outputs into a single layer, and then I would, in theory, have one big model.  Then I would post an answer to my own question. But I would love if someone else beat me to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suggested in comments, you can merge multiple models in one new model and predict using this new model.

First, I write **a function to merge models and return a new combined model**. This is what you want:

```
def concat_horizontal(models, input_shape):
  models_count = len(models)
  hidden = []
  input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)
  for i in range(models_count):
    hidden.append(models[i](input))
  output = tf.keras.layers.concatenate(hidden)
  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input, outputs=output)
  return model
```

Let's explore an example. Say we want merge two sequential models like this:

```
def model_1():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28,1)),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='relu'),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(200, activation='relu'),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='relu'),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')], name="model1")
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

def model_2():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28,1)),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='relu'),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(150, activation='relu'),
                      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')], name="model2")
  model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

model1 = model_1()
model2 = model_2()
```

Let's use MNIST as train dataset for both of our models:

```
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
ds_1 = tfds.load('mnist', split='train', as_supervised=True)
ds_2 = tfds.load('mnist', split='test', as_supervised=True)

def map_fn(image, label):
  image = image / 255
  return image, label

ds_1 = ds_1.map(map_fn).shuffle(1024).batch(32)
ds_2 = ds_2.map(map_fn).shuffle(1024).batch(32)
```

Now, we can train models, save them, and then load them like this:

```
model1.fit(ds_1, epochs=2, validation_data=ds_1)
model2.fit(ds_2, epochs=2, validation_data=ds_2)

model1.save('model1.h5')
model2.save('model2.h5')

model3 = tf.keras.models.load_model('model1.h5')
model4 = tf.keras.models.load_model('model2.h5')
```

So we have 2 separate models (`model3`,`model4`) and want to merge these, to a new one. Pass them along the input shape (in this case it is MNIST data shape) to the function we have written above:

```
new_model = concat_horizontal([model3,model4],(28,28,1))
```

Now, if we plot this new model:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(new_model)
```

[image: new_model_plot]

It's time to get predictions of model:

```
sample = ds_1.unbatch().take(1)
for i,j in sample:
  img = i
  lbl = j
img = tf.expand_dims(img,axis=0)
pred = new_model.predict(img)
pred = np.reshape(pred,(2,10))
results = np.argmax(pred,axis=1)
print(results)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.imshow(np.array(img).squeeze())
plt.show
```

In my case I get both of predictions classified as 4:

Output:

[image: predictions]

Comment: Implemented this suggestion, and it totally works! Very happy and grateful to @Kaveh