# Merge multiple Models in Keras (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

After doing a lot of effort here is my question,

I have two models, both models can detect 2-2 classes. As we know that we can merge two models using a FunctionalAPI. I tried it, But I am not getting the desired outcome.

My goal: I want to Merge these models, and the updated model should have (1 input, 4 output).

```
inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(50,50,1))
y_1 = f1_Model(inputs)
y_2 = f2(inputs)
outputs = tf.concat([y_1, y_2], axis=0)
new_model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
new_model.summary()
```

```
Model: "functional_5"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_2 (InputLayer)            [(None, 50, 50, 1)]  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential (Sequential)         (None, 2)            203874      input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
sequential_1 (Sequential)       (None, 2)            203874      input_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
tf_op_layer_concat (TensorFlowO [(None, 2)]          0           sequential[1][0]                 
                                                                 sequential_1[1][0]               
==================================================================================================
Total params: 407,748
Trainable params: 407,748
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

When I pass an image in it, it gives the wrong result. I don't know where did I go wrong.

```
prediction = new_model.predict([prepare(img)]) 
prediction

# index_pred=np.argmax(prediction) (this should return from 0 to 3, but not happening)
 

array([[1., 0.],
       [1., 0.]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: It looks like you need to change axis along which you concatenate your outputs. `outputs = tf.concat([y_1, y_2], axis=1)` should work.

Comment: `array([[0., 1., 1., 0.]],`  tried it, and but this is wrong. I think there is only one which should 1 and rest should be 0

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68036757/how-to-merge-classification-models-horizontally/68050494#68050494

Comment: @Kaveh i will try. till then please read the comments which I added in the below answer. let me know if it is doable with your suggested solution

Comment: @Kaveh https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/97733/model-update-in-real-time this is also my question

Comment: No, you don't need to train them again.

Comment: @Kaveh you see his comment! i am facing that issue as well, can you please tell me how to deal with classes(because both model has 2-2 classes which are labeled as 1 and 0)

Comment: He is right. In my suggestion, you don't have to train, but you will get both model prediction, and you have to handle their output yourself. But if you are trying to add another layer, with 4 neurons, you have to retrain your model. Note that you can freeze the first layers, to avoid changing their weights, and just tuning your last layers. Then your train time will reduce significantly, because you are just tuning few last layers.

Comment: @Kaveh can you please suggest links, how to freeze the layers and train the rest!

Comment: There is lots of transfer learning example, which freeze some or all part of a pre-trained model, and add their own classification layer at the top of model. [Here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning#feature_extraction) is an example, which uses a pre-trained model to feature extraction and adds his own classification layer to that model.

Comment: @Kaveh thanks! i will try this approach.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you want to classify 4 classes and for that, you have 2 models which classify 2 classes each. 
As of now, your f1 and f2 model outputs the result of `softmax activation` so first, you have to remove it and output just the logits or just `relu activation`. After that as mentioned by the @dmg2, you have to set the `axis=1` in the `tf.concat` now at the end you have to pass the output through a new `softmax` activation. After that, I hope you could train your model.

Comment: both models are already trained. after the merge, Do I need to train again?  There is no other way? because training will take a lot of time.  I can use two models separately but I want to merge them.

Comment: no other way. you have to train. to give you the reason. The first model thinks that it is either class 1 or class2 while the second model thinks it is either class 3 or class 4 so for each input the first model will say its class 1 or class 2 and second will say either 3 or 4 so the end you will have 2 very high logits after the concat. and hence the softmax probas will vary very slightly.